# OAuth - Where can I catch the "redirect URI" calling back my app from an outside browser?

Tags: objective-c, oauth-2.0

I have to open the whole OAuth Login process in an outside browser window and not in any UIWebView within the app. So my redirect URI already opens my app correctly. But in which method or where exactly can I catch the data that is sent back to the app?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a URLScheme in your app and calling it from the browser to reopen your app. In which case you can add the data you need as parameters to the URL like this:

```
yourscheme://oath?token=1234567890&refresh_token=0987654321
```

Then in your app implement the `-(BOOL)application:openURL:options:` method like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
    NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"scheme: %@", [url scheme]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
    if ([url.host isEqualToString:@"oath"]) {
        // Use NSString methods to extract the data from the URL
    }
}
```